# A Wallet for many blockchains (not just the bitcoin blockchain)

Tags: blockchain, wallet, bip32-hd-wallets

In terms of the future of the trust network where there will be an increasing number of fit-for-purpose blockchains such as ones for proof of asset, proof of identity, proof of ownership etc., will there be a wallet to store all of an individual's blockchain needs?

Much like our conventional wallet now storing our cash, driver's license, credit cards and affinity cards. Is the BIP32 "standard" moving in this direction?

Answer (score 3):

The Exodus Project might be of interest: http://www.exodus.io
It's a multi-currency desktop wallet with shapeshift (altcoin exchange) already built-in. You can already download a beta version of it, official launch is going to be this summer according to the projects homepage.

I can't find an example better than https://www.omniwallet.org right now, but I think there have been other multi-currency online wallets around for a while. Exodus however is the first dektop multi-currency wallet I know of.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technological reason preventing the creation of a single application that communicates with several peer-to-peer blockchain networks, and manages private keys for all of them.  If a blockchain-based future is eminent, then there will be a need for both personal wallets and point-of-sale systems that handle multiple blockchains.  That means that someone will almost certainly create them.

Right now, I don't think the need is high enough, but I'm sure someone has started building one anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need a domain addressing scheme. Where domains are like:

- Bitcoin
- Amazon digital media library
- Apple iTunes media library
- Joe Blog's digital art library
- Government digital cryptocurrency

Where each domain implements their own blockchain. Allowing us the ability to store all our rights in a wallet or wallets of our choice.